# Can I rewrite this loop in R using `lapply`?

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a script in R which I am attempting to use to separate several data frames by a certain variable. I am currently using a loop to do this and wondering if I can instead use `lapply` or a similar function.

The loop essentially takes a data frame, `df`, which has a column called `Time`. The time values are in hours and range from 0-48 by multiples of six (which is what the index list contains).

The code should create a new dataframe called data.time.0 consisting of all rows where time = 0, and so on for every value of time.

```
library(tidyverse)

index = seq(from = 0, to = 48, by = 6)

for (i in index) {
  name = paste("data.time."+i,sep = "")
  currentdf = filter(df,df$time == i)
  assign(name,currentdf)
}
```

However, I have heard that using `assign` should be avoided when possible, and I would like to use a vector operation rather than a loop. Is this possible? How would I do it?

Comment: `split(df, df$time)`?

Comment: Take @Roland's advice; much better to use `split()` and get a list than use `assign()`.

Comment: I did not know that `split()` existed. So if I do `split(df,df$time)<-paste("data.time.", seq(from = 0, to = 48, by = 6),sep = "")` this will give me a list containing all the data frames I want?

Comment: No; you'd save the result from `split` into a new variable: `split_df <- split(df,df$time)`. That new variable will be a list of data frames. I believe the default names will be the values from `df$time` (as strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct translation to `lapply()` would be

```
mylist <- lapply(seq(from = 0, to = 48, by = 6), function(x){
  filter(df, df$time == x)
})

names(mylist) <- paste("data.time.", seq(from = 0, to = 48, by = 6),sep = "")
```

I agree with @Roland's comment, though. It is very likely that there's a simpler approach.

Comment: If I do this either way and get a list of data frames is it possible to use `lapply` to do `aov` on each data frame in the list? My guess is that there is an easier, better way to do this whole operation but I do not know what it is. I do not know enough about Tidyverse to know if it has a built-in way of doing this.

Comment: `lapply(mylist, aov)`